# classifying map of associated bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes, classifying-spaces

Let $G\leq GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a group and $\xi$ be a principal $G$-bundle over a space $X$.

Let $\eta=\xi[\mathbb{R}^n]$ be the associated vector bundle of $\xi$.

Let $f_\xi: X\to BG$ be the classifying map of $\xi$.

Let $f_\eta:X\to G_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ be the classifying map of $\eta$.

Let $i_*: BG\to  G_n(\mathbb{R}^\infty)$ the induced map by inclusion $i:G\to GL(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Are $i_*\circ f_\xi\simeq f_\eta$ homotopy equivalent?

Comment: Depending on exactly how you construct associated bundles, classifying maps, and classifying spaces, the best you can say without more information is that the two maps are homotopic.

Comment: I am confused.. Why?

Comment: Classifying spaces and classifying maps are only well-defined up to homotopy equivalence and homotopy respectively.